# Getting Viewbag value returns undefined in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am setting viewbag value in hidden field in Razor page and Trying to get that value from Jquery on document.ready function but it returns undefined.
When I am checking that field's value by inspect element I can see value is setting correctly.
How Can I Get that value??
Here is my code:

cshtml:

```
<input type="hidden" id= "hdnShowPreferences" name="hdnShowPreferences" value="@(ViewBag.ShowPrefrences ==  null? "true":"false")" />
```

JQuery (inside document.ready):

```
var showPrefrences=  $("hdnShowPreferences").val();
console.log(showPrefrences);
```

Comment: you miss `#` before `hdnShowPreferences`  i.e : `$("#hdnShowPreferences")`

Comment: Such a silly mistake... Thanks :)